# Export function to DLL without class

Tags: c++, function, dllexport

Is there a way to export only a function to DLL cos in tutorials they always export classes with something like:

```
 static __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);
```

Inside a class the statement above does not cause any problem, but without a class it gives:

```
 dllexport/dllimport requires external linkage
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is the "static" qualifier.  You need to remove it because it means the wrong thing in this context.  Try just:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);
```

That's what you need to have in your header file when compiling the DLL.  Now to access the function from a program that uses the DLL, you need to have a header file with this:

```
double Add(double a, double b);
```

You can use the **same** header file for both purposes if you use #ifdefs:

```
#ifndef MYDLL_EXPORT
  #define MYDLL_EXPORT
#endif

MYDLL_EXPORT double Add(double a, double b);
```